# Polymer - Side scroll between paper-card

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I am new to Polymer and it has been a while since I HTML'd, so I have been using stack-overflow and Google's polymer guide.
Now to the point: I am working on a product catalogue and I am already coding the paper-cards I will use for the products and its layout. However, I am having trouble to find a container that allows me to browse among cards (see image)

[image: This is my general idea]

Through the Polymer catalogue I have only found the swipeable option which does not suit me as I want to scroll.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use CSS for this. Style the container and `paper-card` with `overflow-x` and `white-space` as follows:

```
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
paper-card {
  width: 350px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        .container {
          width: 50%;
          overflow-x: auto;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }
        paper-card {
          margin: 10px;
          width: 350px;
          white-space: normal;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="container">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
          <paper-card heading="Emmental" image="http://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
            <div class="card-content">
              Emmentaler or Emmental is a yellow, medium-hard cheese that originated in the area around Emmental, Switzerland. It is one of the cheeses of Switzerland, and is sometimes known as Swiss cheese.
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-actions">
              <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
              <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
            </div>
          </paper-card>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({is: 'x-foo'});
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BLVdbL?editors=1000)</sup>